# How to use QGraphicsView in Qt?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I need to create a view like this in Qt

[image: QGraphicsView]

If I click the circle then it'll give a popup message like this "You clicked 2 circle."

I need to add the circle during run time in any location. How to implement this in Qt using `QGraphicsView`? Or are there any other better way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

The following page from Qt documentation can help you: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html
The [Drag and drop example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-dragdroprobot-example.html) will help you to know how deals with your `QGraphicItems`

Hope that helps

Comment: Example is great. i need to know to implement the Circle click event. once the circle clicked i need to pass the Signal to Parent widget. i tried, but it's give the compiler error. Please help to implement the Click event.